# 500 - Internal server error after publishing redirect in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have the following redirect for a page with a new URL:

```
[RoutePrefix("eventos-online")]
public class OnlineEventsController : Controller
{
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("contacto")]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
         return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "OnlineEvents") + "#contacte-nos");
    }
}
```

On my laptop (`localhost`), everything works fine, after publishing to production - https://www.izigo.pt/eventos-online/contacto - I get:

> 500 - Internal server error.
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

EDIT: Found the issue, there was a Web.config file with the redirect in a "contacto" folder in the IIS main folder of the application. Removed the folder, problem solved.

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Comment: check production server has the necessary permissions to perform the redirect.

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN There are no permissions required to issue a HTTP 3xx response in ASP.NET nor IIS.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, Jackdaw, MD.RAKIBHASAN, Dai, Thank You for taking the time to comment my question, in the meanwile I found the issue and post the answer.

Comment: @Dai https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN how is that relevant to my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep searching, I found a Web.config file inside a "contacto" folder of the Web Application IIS folder with the redirect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.izigo.pt/eventos-online#contacte-nos" exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After removing the folder, problem solved.

The strange thing here is that renaming the route to [Route("contactos")] was working fine in the production server, this is why I start searching in that direction.